# UICollectionView is not scrolling smooth on reload data

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uicollectionview

In my UICollecitonView, I am appending data from API using

self.DataTableCollectionView.reloadData()

But as data in my collection gets increasing, its scrolling becomes rough and after loading some pages, it becomes very hard to scroll up or down. It is getting stuck.

Eventually when I tried to load 1000 rows at a time scrolling works smooth but when I try to paginate and load 50 rows at a time using API, then it becomes hard to scroll.

What would be the problem can any one help me out?

I am not able to figure out what iss wrong? Is self.DataTableCollectionView.reloadData() reponsible for this?

Here is the code to load data on scroll :

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

     let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
     let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height

     if(offsetY > (contentHeight - scrollView.frame.size.height)){              

         let seconds = 3.0
         let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
         let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

         self.loadMoreData()
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
             self.DataTableCollectionView.reloadData()

         })                
      }        

}
```

==========

I am reusing the cells as

```
self.DataTableCollectionView .registerNib(UINib(nibName: "DCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: dCellIdentifier)
self.DataTableCollectionView .registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cCellIdentifier)
```

and for reusing:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let dCell : DCollectionViewCell = collectionView .dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(dCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DCollectionViewCell

let cCell : ContentCollectionViewCell = collectionView .dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CCollectionViewCell       
}
```

=========

Adding more specific code:

Now I have Updated my scrolling function,

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height
    if(offsetY > (contentHeight - scrollView.frame.size.height)){
       var returnTableData = NSMutableArray()

       self.InspectPageId = self.InspectPageId+1
       self.dataSource.populateData(PageId:self.InspectPageId)
       returnTableData = self.dataSource.DTableDataArray

       if(returnTableData.count>0){
          for i in 0..<returnTableData.count {
             self.TableDataArray.addObject(returnTableData[i])
          }
       }
       self.NumberOfRows = self.TableDataArray.count

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
          self.DataTableCollectionView.reloadData()
       })
   }
}
```

Following is the code for creating collection view manually:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
//Here Header Cell is creating
                let dateCell : DateCollectionViewCell = collectionView .dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(dateCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DateCollectionViewCell
                dateCell.dateLabel.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue", size: 12)
                dateCell.dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                dateCell.dateLabel.textAlignment = .Left
                dateCell.dateLabel.text = UMIDDataArray[rowIndex-1] as? String
                dateCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                dateCell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
                dateCell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
                return dateCell
            } else {
//Here Data Cell is Creating
                let contentCell : ContentCollectionViewCell = collectionView .dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(contentCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ContentCollectionViewCell
                contentCell.contentLabel.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue", size: 12)
                contentCell.contentLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                contentCell.contentLabel.textAlignment = .Left
                contentCell.bottomBorder.hidden  = false
                contentCell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
                contentCell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

                let LensData:NSArray =  TableDataArray[rowIndex-1] as! NSArray
                let ColumnValue = LensData[colIndex-1] as? String
                contentCell.contentLabel.text = ColumnValue
                contentCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

                return contentCell
            }

Following is the code which is use to take data from API:

//function of DataSource Class.
func populateData(PageId:Int){
var returnData = NSMutableArray()
let OtherColobjects = NSMutableArray()

let Urlpath = SetApiUrl()
let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: Urlpath)!
let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
(data, response, error) in

guard error == nil else {
return
}

guard let responseData = data else {
return
}

do {
guard let Data = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] else {
return
}

for anItem in Data["result"]!["DATA"] as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
let d1 = self.checkForNull(anItem["data1"]!)
let d2 = self.checkForNull(anItem["data2"]!)
let d3 = self.checkForNull(anItem["data3"]!)
let d4 = self.checkForNull(anItem["data4"]!)
...... // Total 20 Columns

let obj = [ d1, d2, d3, d4,.............,d20 ]

OtherColobjects.addObject(obj)
}
dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
} catch {
return
}
}
task.resume()

dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
self.NumberOfRows = returnData[0].count
self.DTableDataArray = returnData[1] as! NSMutableArray
}
```

Comment: are you reusing your collectionview cells?

Comment: Yes, I am reusing your collectionview.

Comment: I added code in the question.

Comment: are you caching images ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only update your UI from the main thread, so do this instead...

**Swift 2.x** :

```
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()), {
                self.DataTableCollectionView.reloadData()
            }
```

**Swift 3** :

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.DataTableCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

If that doesn't solve the problem then you may ALSO need to call `loadMoreData()` on a background thread...

**Swift 2.x** :

```
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY, 0)){
             self.loadMoreData()
        }
```

**Swift 3** :

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {
     self.loadMoreData()
}
```

It is unclear exactly how your code works since you have not shown us your `loadMoreData()` function. It actually seems thats you may be meaning to call `DataTableCollectionView.reloadData()` from inside `loadMoreData` , but I cannot tell without seeing the function. Please add the additional code

Comment: you still haven't added the 'loadMoreData()' function and you removed the call to 'loadMoreData()` from 'scrollViewDidScroll'

Comment: yes, I have updated my question,
I have attached the updated "scrollViewDidScroll()" function,
and now there in no more "loadMoreData()" function and code of loadMoreData() function is added in "scrollViewDidScroll()" function

Answer (score 2):

add following 2 lines after your dequeue cell,

```
cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

Comment: I have added these two lines and as well as collectionview's prefetch method. Thanks buddy for your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should dispatch the `reloadData()` on `MainThread` instead. Manipulating UI should always done in `MainThread` according to apple documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If `self.loadMoreData()` is not asynchronous, it's blocking your UI.
`self.DataTableCollectionView.reloadData()` should be called on main thread from `self.loadMoreData()`.

Even if that wasn't blocking, you're calling `loadMoreData()` multiple times per page.
You should add a boolean for checking whether you're already loading data, let's call it `isLoading`.
Set `isLoading` to false when you initialise viewcontroller.
In `self.loadMoreData()` set it to true, and change check in `scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)` so it looks like this:

```
if(offsetY > (contentHeight - scrollView.frame.size.height)) && !isLoading{  
    self.loadMoreData()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Disabling animations before reload data

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
collectionView.reloadItems(indexPaths)
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Reload collocation in main queue**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
   self.DataTableCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try moving your reload collectionview from scrollviewdidscroll to loadmoredata()

func loadmoredata(){

/*
 1. List item
 2. and then call realoadata at the end
 3. and if you have images in cells , then use image caching , either you can program image caching or use libraries like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)
*/

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {self.DataTableCollectionView.reloadData()})

}